# What's the replacement of Directive in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I've been learning Angular2. I observed that 'directive' tag was used inside @Component metadata in RC version to refer another component in it. But there is no 'directive' tag associated with it in Ang version 2.1.0. how am I supposed to refer another component now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare **`directives`** in **`declarations`** meta property of **`@NgModule`** as shown below (as **`directives`** meta property has been removed from **`@Component`** decorator)

```
@NgModule({
  imports      : [ BrowserModule, .... ],
  declarations : [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent    //<<<### here it is another component or directive,
    HighlightDirective    //<<<### directive declared with @Directive decorator
  ],
  providers    : [  ],
  bootstrap    : [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

for more information you can refer to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: Thanks a lot micronyks for the response, but is this the only way? Can't I use a tag inside Component for referring? I saw there was a tag 'entryComponent' is allowed inside @Component, but it's not working like directive. please clarify.

Comment: entryCompoent is used when you want to inject component dynamically. but for static cmp you could go with shown way...